# Python Pivot Table conditional count

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to generate a pivot table with following result
wondering how i calculate the # of win, lost, and draw....
essentially, I want to say count only if Result == 'Win'

I didn't want to use Result as a column because I don't want to have Speed breakdown by Win/Lost/Draw...is there a way to just count # of

```
Name    Result     Win   Loss   Draw   Speed
James    6         2      2      2       50
Bob      9         7      2      0       48
Mary     10        5      3      2       70
```

This is the code

```
report = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["Name"], values=["Result", "Speed"],  aggfunc= {"Result": len, "Speed": np.mean}, fill_value=0)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: "Count the number of" what, exactly?

Comment: @jrd1 I am trying to count number of Win/Loss/Draw, in Result Column, it is a string of either Win/Loss/Draw....so when I do "len", i get number of Results....but I want to filter on number of Wins....so I guess len only if wins?

Comment: @jrd1 in other word, while Result: len gives me how many game each person plays, is there a way for me to count # of Wins....without have Result as a column

Comment: Is that table what your data looks like or is that the `report` variable?

Comment: @IanThompson report will be the output, and yes, the example table above is example output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data looks something like this:

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name' : ['James']*6 +\
             ['Bob']*9 +\
             ['Mary']*10,
    'Result' : ['Win']*2 + ['Loss']*2 + ['Draw']*2 +\
               ['Win']*7 + ['Loss']*2 +\
               ['Win']*5 + ['Loss']*3 + ['Draw']*2,
    'Speed' : [50]*6 +\
              [48]*9 +\
              [70]*10
})
```

[image: df]

Then just filter on 'Win' and pivot:

```
# Filter on 'Win'; make pivot table
df[df.Result == 'Win'].pivot_table(index = 'Name',
                                   values = ['Result', 'Speed'],
                                   aggfunc = {'Result' : 'count',
                                              'Speed' : 'mean'},
                                   fill_value = 0).rename(columns = {'Result' : 'Win'})
```

Or groupby and aggregate:

```
# groupby.agg()
df[df.Result == 'Win'].groupby('Name').agg({'Result' : 'count',
                                            'Speed' : 'mean'}).rename({'Result' : 'Win'})
```

Same results:

[image: result]